# Electron exits without emiting render-process-gone event

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

When I press a button on a certain website loaded in a `BrowserView`, the electron app exits. It's obviously a crash, but it doesn't emit the `render-process-gone` neither on the BrowserWindow (renderer) or the BrowserView. It just quits. But `window-all-closed` is emited

```
app.on('ready', () => {
  app.on('render-process-gone', (e, webContents, details) => {
    console.log('render-process-gone', details);
  });

  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    frame: false,    
    webPreferences: {
      worldSafeExecuteJavaScript: true,
      nodeIntegration: true,
      webviewTag: false,
      enableRemoteModule: false,
    }
  });

  win.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/renderer.html');

  const view = new BrowserView({
    webPreferences: {
      preload: 'preload.js'
      worldSafeExecuteJavaScript: true,
      nodeIntegration: false,
      nodeIntegrationInSubFrames: true,
      enableRemoteModule: false,
    }
  });

  view.webContents.loadURL('http://website.com');

  view.webContents.on('render-process-gone', (e, details) => {
    console.log('render-process-gone', details);
  });

  win.setBrowserView(view);  

});

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  console.log('exiting...');
  app.quit();
});
```

Is there a way to find out what could be causing this?

---

update: I added `sandbox: true` to the webPreferences and now it doesn't crash anymore!

Comment: are you on electron 10? The event was added in 10 ([release notes](https://www.electronjs.org/releases/stable#release-notes-for-v1000)), though the docs will show the latest version's docs and will include it, so you may have found an example in the docs and used it though your Electron version doesn't support it

Comment: Your electron version is?

Comment: And which os are you using?

Comment: it happens on both latest macos and windows 7

Comment: So the below answer is showing that the `render-process-gone` event has been added instead of `render-process-crashed`

Comment: I think you can get this `app.on('render-process-gone')` if you are using over 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Emitted when the renderer process crashes or is killed.

**Deprecated:** This event is superceded by the `render-process-gone` event
which contains more information about why the render process dissapeared. It
isn't always because it crashed.  The `killed` boolean can be replaced by
checking `reason === 'killed'` when you switch to that event.

#### Event: 'render-process-gone'

Returns:

* `event` Event
* `details` Object
  * `reason` String - The reason the render process is gone.  Possible values:
    * `clean-exit` - Process exited with an exit code of zero
    * `abnormal-exit` - Process exited with a non-zero exit code
    * `killed` - Process was sent a SIGTERM or otherwise killed externally
    * `crashed` - Process crashed
    * `oom` - Process ran out of memory
    * `launch-failure` - Process never successfully launched
    * `integrity-failure` - Windows code integrity checks failed

Emitted when the renderer process unexpectedly dissapears.  This is normally
because it was crashed or killed.
```

- Added new `render-process-gone` event on app to replace the `renderer-process-crashed` event. #23560
- Added new `render-process-gone` event to replace the crashed event. #23096

REF: https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/23096

https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/23560